# Stacking multiple plots together with a single x-axis

Tags: matplotlib

Suppose I have multiple time dependent variables and I want to plot them all together stacked one of on top of another like the image below, how would I do so in matplotlib? Currently when I try plotting them they appear as multiple independent plots.
[image]

EDIT: 
I have a Pandas dataframe with K columns corresponding to dependent variables and N rows corresponding to observed values for those K variables.

Sample code:

```
df = get_representation(mat) #df is the Pandas dataframe
for i in xrange(len(df.columns)):
    plt.plot(df.ix[:,i])
    plt.show()
```

I would like to plot them all one on top of another.

Comment: In your case it might be easiest to just add an offset to each individual curve, effectively shifting them vertically.

Comment: @DavidZwicker Could you give me an example?

Comment: If you post some example code, I could modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just stack all the curves by shifting each curve vertically:

```
df = get_representation(mat) #df is the Pandas dataframe
for i in xrange(len(df.columns)):
    plt.plot(df.ix[:, i] + shift*i)
plt.show()
```

Here `shift` denotes the average distance between the curves.